# Creating variation labels using CSOM in sharepoint 2013

Tags: client-object-model, variations

Can anyone tell me how to create variation labels using CSOM?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I dont think you can create the variation label using the CSOM. I think you need to use to the Powershell or c#. here is the blog:

[Automate Variations in SharePoint 2013 Using PowerShell & C#](http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2013/7/23/automate-variations-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell-c)

He wrote the code for both C# and script for PowerShell.

Comment: Is there any reason to down vote? You did it could you please tell me why?

Comment: The answer has been downvoted since Iam pretty sure it is incorrect, I guess it is based only on googling..but it does not mean it could not be done. See for example this answer sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88367/… Evidently the same approach could be applied for creating variation labels. Besides in SharePoint 2013 API was introduced Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing namespace that contains VariationLabel class, if you are really interested, see for example msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh627977(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: but question is can you create the label? which i think you cannot.

Answer (score 11):

### How to create Variation Labels in SharePoint 2013/Online via CSOM

SharePoint 2010/2013 CSOM API does not expose any specific methods for creating Variation Labels, but you could use the following class for that purpose.

[VariationsClient class](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/6757a1dab43eb320aa6c) is intended for managing `Variation Labels` in SharePoint 2013.
The following operations are currently supported:

- `VariationsClient.CreateLabel` method is used for create Variation Label
- `VariationsClient.GetLabelsList` method gets Variation Labels on site

### Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
    var variationsClient = new VariationsClient(ctx);
    var siteLanguages = new[] {"en-US","ru-RU","fi-FI","nl-NL"};
    foreach (var language in siteLanguages)
    {
        var isSource = (language == "en-US");
        variationsClient.CreateLabel(new CultureInfo(language), isSource);    
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]